# Create local variables programmatically (in Lua)

Tags: lua

Been having fun with a homebrew doco system in Lua. e.g.

```lua
fun("abs","return abs value", function (x,y)
        return math.abs(x,y) end)
```

I'm stuck on one detail. I want to make "abs" a local function . But I do not know how to do that programmatically.

Of course, I could write to a field in some Lib object and call it `Lib.abs(x,y)` and I think that is what I'm going to have to do. **BUT** can any smart Lua person tell me how to not do that?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have much of a choice, as while you can assign a value to a local variable (using [debug.setlocal](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-debug.setlocal) function), it's assigned by index, not by name, so there has to exist a local variable already with that index.

I don't see anything wrong with your suggestion to store the function in a table field.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is, I'd write(or even override) _G, run your function/program, and then restore it.

```
function callSandboxed(newGlobals, func)
    local oldGlobals = {} --make a new table to store the values to be writen (to make sure we don't lose any values)
    for i,_ in pairs(newGlobals) do
        table.insert(oldGlobals, _G[i]) --Store the old values
        _G[i] = newGlobals[i] --Write the new ones
    end
    func() --Call your function/program with the new globals
    for i,v in pairs(oldGlobals) do
        _G[i] = v --Restore everything
    end
end
```

In this case, what you want to do is:

```
--Paste the callSandboxed function

callSandboxed({abs=math.abs},function()print(abs(-1))end) --Prints 1
```

If you want to remove ALL the old values from _G (not only the ones you want to replace), then you could use this:

```
function betterCallSandboxed(newGlobals, func) --There's no point deep copying now, we will replace the whole table
    local oldGlobals = _G --Make a new table to store the values to be writen (to make sure we don't lose any values)
    _G = newGlobals --Replace it with the new one
    func() --Call your function/program with the new globals
    _G = oldGlobals
end
```

Now if inside `func`, `print` and `math`(etc) are nil.

Comment: rewrite \_G? (or in  Lua 5+, rewrite \_ENV)?

interesting approach.

 does _G=_ENV={abs=math.abs} mean that  everything else  in the global environment is now in accessible?

Comment: Oh, thanks for telling me about _ENV. I'm used to working with old versions of lua, so I haden't realised this new _ENV thing. I think I'll stick to _G, though, for compatibility